# Rails multiple routes, same `as`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following routes:

```
authenticated :user do
    scope module: 'admin', path: ':publisher_id' do
      get 'settings/general', to: 'publishers#index', as: 'publisher_settings'
      post 'settings/general', to: 'publishers#create'
      put 'settings/general', to: 'publishers#update'
    end
end
```

However the first `as:` can only be used once. How can I make this apply to all these routes? I want all of them to work for the `publisher_settings_path`

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass the `as` option to namespaces and scopes in Rails Routes.

```
# prefix the routing helper name: +sekret_posts_path+ instead of +posts_path+
scope as: "sekret" do
  resources :posts
end
```

Source: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html

This should also work though i think

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 resources :publishers, only: [:create, :update, :index], path: 'settings/general', as: 'publisher_settings'
end
```

Get's me

```
 publisher_settings GET   /settings/general(.:format)     publishers#index
                   POST  /settings/general(.:format)     publishers#create
 publisher_setting PATCH /settings/general/:id(.:format) publishers#update
                   PUT   /settings/general/:id(.:format) publishers#update
```

Comment: Yes the last option is the closest but it doesn't get the request which is to have them all as `publisher_settings_path`. They also end up with an ID at the end of the path on the last two

Comment: How would a put or patch request be RESTFUL without an ID? I think you're looking for a solution that Rails really doesn't want you to have ;) Rails is quite opinionated when it comes to being RESTFUL.

Answer (score 0):

`publisher_settings_path` already returns the path of of the three routes, e.g. `/admin/settings/general`. So you don't need to set `as:` multiple times.

And actually setting the same `as:` multiple times for multiple routes would not make sense, it has to return one value.